# Java concurrency question - synchronizing on a collection

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-memory-model

Will the following code snippet of a synchronized `ArrayList` work in a multi-threaded environment?

```
class MyList {
    private final ArrayList<String> internalList = new ArrayList<String>();

    void add(String newValue) {
        synchronized (internalList) {
            internalList.add(newValue);
        }
    }

    boolean find(String match) {
        synchronized (internalList) {
            for (String value : internalList) {
                if (value.equals(match)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm concerned that one thread wont be able to see changes by another thread.

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using `List.contains(match)`? in `find()`?

Comment: Also, I think you are better off using a Set rather than a list.  Finding an element in Set is much faster.

Comment: Just a quick example, the code is a bit contrived.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, because synchronizing on the same object establishes a happens-before relationship, and writes that happen-before reads are guaranteed to be visible.

See the [Java Language Specification, section 17.4.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.4.5) for details on happens-before.

Comment: Thanks, so another thread is guaranteed to see any changes because of the `synchronize` flushes the array list state?

Comment: Actually, this is not a problem with flushing, but with optimizations done by the JIT. The JIT assumes that fields are only modified by the current thread, unless the fields are accessed within a synchronized block, or are volatile. For details, check the JLS.

Answer (score 5):

Your code will work and is thread-safe but not concurrent. You may want to consider using `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` or other concurrent thread-safe data structures like `ConcurrentHashMap` or `CopyOnWriteArraySet` suggested by notnoop and employ `contains` method.

```
class MyList {
    private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> internalList = 
         new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>();

    void add(String newValue) {
        internalList.add(newValue);
    }

    boolean find(String match) {
        return internalList.contains(match);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also consider using `ConcurrentHashMap` or `CopyOnWriteArraySet`, as those would significantly increase your `find` operation

Comment: Apologies that my code was a bit simplified. The actual code stores objects and need to perform custom action.

Answer (score 2):

It will work fine, because all access to the list is synchronized. Hovewer, you can use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` to improve concurrency by avoiding locks (especially if you have many threads executing `find`).

Answer (score 2):

It will work, but better solution is to create a `List` by calling `Collections.synchronizedList()`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using a Set(Tree or Hash) for your data as you are doing lookups by a key.  They have methods that will be much faster than your current find method.

```
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
Boolean result = set.contains(match); // O(1) time
```